# Push message with Firebase cloud messaging - Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I try to send a push message with Google's firebase cloud messaging. I and get this very basic error:

`Request contains an invalid argument.`

```json
{
  "notification": {
    "title": "15:06: Change in planning",
    "body": "There has been a change in your planning today.",
    "image": "https://my-site/logo.jpg"
  },
  "webpush": {
    "notification": {
      "title": "15:06: Change in planning",
      "body": "There has been a change in your planning today.",
      "icon": "https://my-site/logo.jpg"
    },
    "headers": {
      "Urgency": "high",
      "Topic": "tpPlanningNoticeLessThenXTime",
      "TTL": "86400"
    }
  },
  "token": "__a_163_character_token_here__"
}
```

I also tried to send the TTL as integer but no success. The error always happens for messages **to the same user, so could it be that the token is invalid** and I get this very basic error message?

Is there a place where we can test messages for Google's Firebase cloud messaging? Like a sandbox?

For the rules of the push message parts I use these standards: [RFC8030 - Generic Event Delivery Using HTTP Push](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8030)